# Tab stops working after you re-open it

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am building a Tabs menu using this library: https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs. This is how it appears:

[image: Tabs]

The library works well but I had to add a couple of effects. The first effect is the background blur when you click on a tab. The second effect requires the lines below the tabs to be hidden when you click on a tab. These effects work well as you can see below:

[image: Tabs Hover]

Now, here's the problem. When I open a tab, close it and open it again it stops working, the lines (.tablines) can be seen below the text container and the background doesn't get blurred.

[image: Tabs bug]

This is the code:

JS:  http://pastebin.com/4WW5QdPJ

CSS: http://pastebin.com/SeVAnDhi

The JS has some console logs inside. Essentially, this is what happens:

1) Open a tab. ==> console.log:

```
Tab open. Blur added
```

2) Close a tab. ==> console.log:

```
Tab closed. Blur removed
```

3) **Re-open a tab** ==> console.log:

```
Tab open. Blur added
Tab closed. Blur removed
```

What could it be?

Comment: is it that hard to put the code form the pastebin in the question?

Comment: Actually I didn't want to make the message too long for you guys/gals. Thanks for the help!